# How to take only certain value from string?

Tags: android, string, split

I have a URL of youtube as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lLKmJJ68DM&list=PLjwdah_SEU7rDIP_xBDy513_QAkOMG_s_&index=11 and i only want to take the video id (8lLKmJJ68DM) how do i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [Uri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) class

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url_string);
String videoId = uri.getQueryParameter("v");
```

Comment: I would've said to parse the string, splitting on the different delimiters. I didn't know about this, nice one.

Answer (score 1):

On the demo, see the capture groups in the bottom right pane. However, for the second match, not entirely sure that this is a correct ID as it looks different from the other samples—to be tweaked if needed.

In code, something like:

```
String pattern = "(?<=watch\\?v=|/videos/|embed\\/)[^#\\&\\?]*";

Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(url);

if(matcher.find()){
    return matcher.group();
}
```

This one works for: (you could also implement a security check youtubeid length = 11 )

**http://www.youtube.com/embed/Woq5iX9XQhA?html5=1

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=384IUU43bfQ

Woq5iX9XQhA

384IUU43bfQ**

Comment: Yeah that's better only if you expect video URL to contain character 'v' representing video id. URL may contain video id with different tags. So mine is the generic solution. I have also pasted two valid youtube URL's also at the end of my answer.